# Python hangman game loop ending problems

Tags: python

The problem I have is that the game doesn't end because the while loop doesn't end even is the function **is_word_guessed()** returns True.
The rules for the game are:
You have 6 guesses to guess the word. For testing purposes, I am currently using a secret_word='apple'. I'm not adding the code for selecting a random word, it works fine.
If you guess right, you don't lose any guesses.
If you guess wrong, and the guess is a vocal, you lose **2** guesses.
if you guess wrong, and the guess is a consonant, you lose **1** guess.
If you guess a word you already have guessed, or guess a word that is not a letter, or you guess two or more words, you lose 1 warning. You start with 3 warnings, and if you lose them all, you lose one guess. The final score is the number of unique letters on the secret_word*number of guesses_remaining.

```
import string


secret_word='apple'

def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    if secret_word == letters_guessed:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    b=''
    for char in secret_word:
        if char in letters_guessed:
            b=b+char
        else:
            b=b+"_ "
    return b



def get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
    s=''
    letters=string.ascii_lowercase
    for char in letters:
        if char not in letters_guessed:
            s=s+char
    return s


def get_unique_letters(secret_word):
    unique=''
    for char in secret_word:
        if char not in unique:
            unique+=char
    return len(unique)
print (get_unique_letters(secret_word))


def hangman(secret_word):
    print("Welcome to the game of hangman!")
    print ("I am thinking a word that is", str(len(secret_word)), "long.")
    warnings_remaining=3
    guesses_remaining=6
    letters_guessed=''
    while not is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
#        checking that user has guesses left
        if guesses_remaining==0:
            break
        else:
#           checking if we have to remove a guess  
            if warnings_remaining==0:
                guesses_remaining-=1
                warnings_remaining=3          
            print ("---------")
            print("You have", str(guesses_remaining), "guesses left.")
            print("Available letters:", get_available_letters(letters_guessed))
            user_guess=input("Please guess a letter:")
#           checking that the input is a valid letter   
            if len(user_guess) != 1 or user_guess not in string.ascii_letters:
                warnings_remaining-=1
                print("Oops! That is not a valid letter!", "You have", warnings_remaining, "warnings left.")
            elif user_guess in letters_guessed:
                warnings_remaining-=1
                print("Oops! That letter has alredy been guessed. You now have", warnings_remaining, "warnings left.")
#           checking if the guess is right or wrong
            elif user_guess in secret_word:
                letters_guessed+=user_guess
                print ("Good guess:", get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed))
            else: 
                letters_guessed+=user_guess
                print ("Oops! That letter is not in my word:", get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed))
                if user_guess in 'aeiou':
                    guesses_remaining-=2
                else:
                    guesses_remaining-=1

    if guesses_remaining==0:
        print("Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was:", secret_word)
    else:
        print("Congratulations, you won!")
        print("Your total score for this game is:", get_unique_letters(secret_word)*guesses_remaining)

hangman(secret_word)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not accounting for double letters in your `letters_guessed` variable. A quick fix would be to compare the letters only in your `is_word_guessed()` function by converting them to sets:

```
def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    if set(secret_word) == set(letters_guessed):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```